# Remove element from struct type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create this function to remove an element of the user's choosing from a pointer struct array type.

Here is my function. I keep getting this error when my code hits this function.

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1000]’ from type ‘char *’
>
> ```
>       PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName = PhoneBook[x].cFirstName;
> ```

```
void delete_record(pb *PhoneBook)
    {
       int x;
       int iRecord = 0;
    
       print(PhoneBook);
       printf("\nEnter number of record you want to delete: ");
       scanf("%d", &iRecord);
    
       printf("\nRecord to be deleted: %d. %s\n", iRecord - 1, PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName);
       for (x = strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x <= strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x--) {
          PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName = PhoneBook[x].cFirstName;
       }
       printf("\nModified record: %s\n\n",PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName);
    }
```

Here's the full code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct phonebook {
   char cFirstName[1000];
   char cLastName[1000];
   char cNumber[1000];
} pb;

int entry(pb *);
void modify(pb *);
void delete_record(pb *);
void print(pb *);
void convert_u(char *);

//global variable
int MAX_NAME_ENTRY = 0;

int main()
{
   int iResponse = 0;
   pb *PhoneBook = (pb *) calloc(0, sizeof(pb));
   
   if (PhoneBook == NULL) {
      printf("\nMemory allocation failed.\n\n");
      return 1;
   }

   do {
      printf("\nPhonebook Menu\n****************\n\n");
      printf("1. Enter new contact\n2. Modify existing contact\n3. Delete contact\n4. Print Phonebook \n5. Exit\n\n");
      printf("Please make selection: ");
      scanf("%d", &iResponse);

      if (iResponse == 1) {
         entry(PhoneBook);
      }
      else if (iResponse == 2) {
         modify(PhoneBook);
      }
      else if (iResponse == 3) {
         delete_record(PhoneBook);
         //printf("\nWorking on it...\n");
      }
      else if (iResponse == 4) {
         print(PhoneBook);
      }
   } while (iResponse != 5);
   
   free(PhoneBook);
   return 0;
}

int entry(pb *PhoneBook)
{
   int x;
   char yes_no[] = "YES";
   pb *newPhoneBook = realloc(PhoneBook, (10 * sizeof(pb)));

   if (newPhoneBook == NULL) {
      printf("\nOut of memory!\n\n");
      return 1;
   }
   else {
      PhoneBook = newPhoneBook;
   }
   if (MAX_NAME_ENTRY == 10) {
      printf("\nMax Number of names entered.\n");
   }  
 
   for (x = MAX_NAME_ENTRY; x < 10; x++) {
      if (MAX_NAME_ENTRY == 9) {
         printf("\nLast entry.\n");
      }  
      if (x > 0) {
         system("clear");
         printf("\nAnother entry(yes/no)? ");
         scanf("%s", yes_no);
         convert_u(yes_no);
      }

      if (strcmp(yes_no, "YES") == 0) {
         printf("\nFirst Name: ");
         scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cFirstName);

         printf("\nLast Name: ");
         scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cLastName);

         printf("\nPhone Number: ");
         scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cNumber);
         MAX_NAME_ENTRY++;
      }
      else if (strcmp(yes_no, "NO") == 0) {
         break;
      }
   }
}

void modify(pb *PhoneBook)
{
   int iModify = 0;
   char name_num[6] = {'\0'};
   print(PhoneBook);
   printf("\nWhich entry would you like to modify? ");
   scanf("%d", &iModify);

   printf("\nModify name or number? ");
   scanf("%s", name_num);
   convert_u(name_num);
   if (strcmp(name_num, "NAME") == 0) {
      printf("\nEnter new name: ");
      scanf("%s %s", PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cFirstName, PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cLastName);
   }
   else if (strcmp(name_num, "NUMBER") == 0) {
      printf("\nEnter new number: ");
      scanf("%s", PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cNumber);
   }
}

void delete_record(pb *PhoneBook)
{
   int x;
   int iRecord = 0;

   print(PhoneBook);
   printf("\nEnter number of record you want to delete: ");
   scanf("%d", &iRecord);

   printf("\nRecord to be deleted: %d. %s\n", iRecord - 1, PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName);
   for (x = strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x <= strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x--) {
      PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName = PhoneBook[x].cFirstName;
   }
   printf("\nModified record: %s\n\n",PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName);
}

void print(pb *PhoneBook)
{
   int x;
  
   for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { 
      if (strlen(PhoneBook[x].cFirstName) == 0 && strlen(PhoneBook[x].cLastName) == 0) {
         break;
      }
      printf("\n%d. Name: %s %s", x + 1, PhoneBook[x].cFirstName, PhoneBook[x].cLastName);
      printf("\n   Number: %s\n\n", PhoneBook[x].cNumber);
   }
}
void convert_u(char *string)
{
   int x;
  
   for (x = 0; x < strlen(string); x++) {
      string[x] = toupper(string[x]);
   }
}
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To copy an array, you either need to use `strcpy` or `memcpy`. You can use `strcpy` if and only if the array contains a NUL terminated string. `memcpy` can be used to copy any array, provided you know the size of the array in bytes.

Comment: You are using `strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName)` as if it had something to do with the number of elements in the array that `PhoneBook` points to.  Obviously, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

An array name is not a modifiable lvalue. Hence, arrays are not *assignable* in `C`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and regarding the *modifiable lvalue*, chapter §6.3.2.1

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type, [...]

You need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) instead to copy the content.

Comment: strcpy(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName, '\0');

Comment: So then would I need to copy a null pointer type into the PhoneBook array type? Or how exactly would this work?

Comment: @user3495404 why you would copy a null pointer to the array? If you want your array to be 0 filled, use `memset()` instead.

Comment: @user3495404, I suggest using `memmove()` to move down all the elements of the tail at once.  It will be cleaner, and probably faster, too.

Comment: @SouravGhosh So when I try memset() and memmove() as listed below, it seems to remove or copy all the elements in my array after the one I select. So for example, if I have three names and numbers in my phonebook struct and I choose to delete the 2nd one, those functions are nulling out both the 2nd and 3rd elements in the array.

Comment: memmove(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName, delete, strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName));
   memmove(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cLastName, delete, strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cLastName));
   memmove(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cNumber, delete, strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cNumber));

Comment: Delete being defined as - const char delete[] = {'\0'};

Answer (score 0):

it will not work strcpy,  you have to copy the whole record over the other. then realloc the phonebook to new size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct phonebook {
    char cFirstName[50];
    char cLastName[50];
    char cNumber[50];
} pb;

int     entry();
void    modify();
void    delete_record();
void    print_record(int rec);
void    print();
void    convert_u(char *);

//global variables
int     MAX_NAME_ENTRY = 0;
pb      *PhoneBook  = NULL;

#define     YES     "YES"
#define     NO      "NO"





const char *menu=
                " Phonebook Menu             \n"
                " ****************           \n"
                "                            \n"
                " 1. Enter new contact       \n"
                " 2. Modify existing contact \n"
                " 3. Delete contact          \n"
                " 4. Print Phonebook         \n"
                " 5. Exit                    \n"
                "                            \n"
                " Please make selection: ";



int main(void){

   int      iResponse   = 0;



   do {


      printf("%s",menu);
      scanf("%d", &iResponse);

      switch (iResponse) {
          case  1:
                entry();
                break;
          case  2:
                modify();
                break;
          case  3:
                delete_record();
                break;
          case  4:
                print();

      }

   }  while (iResponse != 5);

   free(PhoneBook);
   return 0;
}


int str_input(const char *text, char *buff){
    printf("%s" , text);
    scanf("%s"  , buff);
}

int entry(void)
{
    int     x;
    char    yes_no[] = YES;
    pb      *newPhoneBook;



    if (MAX_NAME_ENTRY == 10) {
      printf("\nMax Number of names entered.\n");
      return 0;
    }  

    while(1) {


    newPhoneBook = realloc(PhoneBook,(MAX_NAME_ENTRY +1) * sizeof(pb)) ;


    if (!newPhoneBook) {
        perror("entry::realloc()");
        return 1;
    }


    PhoneBook = newPhoneBook;






    if (MAX_NAME_ENTRY == 9) {
        printf("\n *** This is the Last entry. *** \n");
    }  

    printf("RECORD: %d\n",MAX_NAME_ENTRY+1);

    str_input("\nFirst Name: "      , PhoneBook[MAX_NAME_ENTRY].cFirstName);
    str_input("\nLast Name: "       , PhoneBook[MAX_NAME_ENTRY].cLastName);
    str_input("\nPhone Number: "    , PhoneBook[MAX_NAME_ENTRY].cNumber);


    MAX_NAME_ENTRY++;

    if(MAX_NAME_ENTRY == 10) 
        break;

    printf("\nAnother entry(yes/no)? ");
    scanf("%s", yes_no);
    convert_u(yes_no);

    if (strcmp(yes_no, YES))
        break;

    system("clear");

   } 

}

int checkRecordExists(int iRecord){
    if(iRecord<1 || iRecord>MAX_NAME_ENTRY){
        printf("Record %d do not exists\n",iRecord);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void modify(void){

    int  iModify = 0;
    char name_num[6] = {'\0'};

    printf("\nWhich entry would you like to modify? ");
    scanf("%d", &iModify);
    if(!checkRecordExists(iModify))
        return;

    iModify --;
    print_record(iModify);

    str_input("\nModify name or number? ", name_num);

    convert_u(name_num);

    if (strcmp(name_num, "NAME") == 0) {
        str_input("\nFirst Name: "      , PhoneBook[iModify].cFirstName);
        str_input("\nLast Name: "       , PhoneBook[iModify].cLastName);
    }
    else if (strcmp(name_num, "NUMBER") == 0) {
        str_input("\nPhone Number: "    , PhoneBook[iModify].cNumber);;
    }

}

void delete_record(void)
{
   int x;
   int iRecord = 0;


   printf("\nEnter number of record you want to delete: ");
   scanf("%d", &iRecord);

   if(!checkRecordExists(iRecord))
        return;


   iRecord--;

   MAX_NAME_ENTRY--;

   for( x=iRecord;x<MAX_NAME_ENTRY;x++)
        memcpy(&PhoneBook[x],&PhoneBook[x+1],sizeof(pb));

    PhoneBook = realloc(PhoneBook,(MAX_NAME_ENTRY + 1) * sizeof(*PhoneBook)  ); 
}


void print_record(int rec){

      printf("\n"
             "%02d. Name: %s %s\n"
             "    Number: %s\n"
             "\n",
             rec + 1, PhoneBook[rec].cFirstName, PhoneBook[rec].cLastName, PhoneBook[rec].cNumber);
   }

}
void print(void){
   int x;
   for (x = 0 ; x < MAX_NAME_ENTRY ; x++) { 
      print_record(x);
   }
}


void convert_u(char *string){
    while(*string){
        *string = toupper(*string);
        string ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you are trying, and that is fine, but please try and avoid "*me too*" answers. Other than reposting code, your answer is verbatim the answer given yesterday. With some answers, there just isn't anything else constructive to add. On the other hand, if you have valid improvements relevant to the question, then please take the time to explain them in an understandable manner. This will help keep the information on the site relevant and non-duplicative.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, i don't understand what you mean by "me too"?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, can you post me where the verbatim answer was posted else where?

Comment: The answer above yours says `You need to use strcpy() instead to copy the content.` Which other than the pasted code is exactly what your answer is.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ahh, OK i see what you mean. but what i mean, is that all  this `for (x = strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x <= strlen(PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName); x--) {
          PhoneBook[iRecord - 1].cFirstName = PhoneBook[x].cFirstName;` will not work,   even if replaced with strcpy. he has to copy the entire block of the next PhoneBook on to the current till then end of the records.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, hey ... it is not me who wrote that `You need to use strcpy() instead to copy the content` please check again.

Comment: Then it would seem you have valid improvements. I apologize for not discerning them earlier. The difficulty I had in seeing them was the complete dearth of information that would easily identify the improvements. Keep up the good work.